# MongoDB Array or Separate collection

Tags: mongodb

I have a users collection.
Each user may have:
 - large number of followers (100K+) and might be following a large number of other users.
 - large list of favorites
 - large list of items viewed

I see 2 design for schema. Regarding the queries, I need to find the people a user following
I also need to know the favorites, watch list of a given user.
All list (followers, following, favorites must have unique entries

I tried to find similar questions or topics by Google but can't find anything.

Can MongoDB handle large array like these or I should go with design approach 2 where store the mapping in separate collections which allow me to have unlimited # of mappings?

I would appreciate your valuable thought.

I am going with option 2 as it allows me to have unlimited number of mappings.
But before I go that route, I want to check if there will be issues that I may not want.

Moving from one design to the other will be expensive.

```
Design 1 (EMBEDDED ARRAY TO STORE MAPPINGS):
[
{
  user: bob, //(key)
  followers: ["Alex", "john", "steve", "mark", ... 200K+ entries]
  following: ["Mila", "mark", "Bill", "Joe", ... 100K+ entries]
  favorites: [ObjectI(1), ObjectId(2),...5K+ entries]
  watched: [ObjectI(4), ObjectId(5),...100K+ entries]
},
{
  user: Nick, //(key)
  followers: [bob", "kery", "Jery", "Tom", ... 200K+ entries]
  following: ["Tim", "Shane", "Sally", "Joe", ... 100K+ entries]
  favorites: [ObjectI(4), ObjectId(5),...5K+ entries]
  watched: [ObjectI(2), ObjectId(9),...100K + entries]
}
]
```

Design 2 (SEPARATE COLLECTIONS TO STORE MAPPINGS)

```
user_followers collection:
[
 { user: bob, follower: "Alex" }, //key: (user, follower)
 { user: bob, follower: "john"}, 
 { user: bob, follower: "steve"}, 
 { user: bob, follower: "mark"}
  ... 200K+ entries
]

user_following collection:
[
 { user: bob, following: "Mila"},  //key (user, following)
 { user: bob, following: "mark"},
 { user: bob, following: "Bill"}, 
 { user: bob, following: "Joe"},
 ... 100K+ entries
]

user_favorites collection:
[
 { user: bob, favorite: ObjectId(1)},
 { user: bob, favorite: ObjectId(3)},
 { user: bob, favorite: ObjectId(6)},
 ... 5k entries
},
```

Comment: Seems that you'll be better off with a regular relational database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can MongoDB handle large array like these or I should go with design approach 2 where store the mapping in separate collections which allow me to have unlimited # of mappings?

In MongoDB, a document can be [at most 16 MB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/). With your first design, you'd risk reaching the limit I suppose.

Regarding the second design though, it seems to me the `user_followers` and `user_following` collections just duplicate the same data: if bob is following martha, then bob is a follower of martha, so you could merge those two collections into one with entries like `{ followed: 'martha', follower: 'bob' }`

**Update**

There's been questions in the comments about how to handle bidirectionnal relationships, or indexes for query.

Given two users bob and martha, they can either have no relationship, or bob follows martha, or martha follows bob, or bob and martha follow each other, i.e. three different possible relations.

Now for the case where bob follows martha, the followers collection would be

```
[
  {
    followed: 'martha',
    follower: 'bob'
  }
]
```

For the case where martha follows bob, it would be

```
[
  {
    followed: 'bob',
    follower: 'martha'
  }
]
```

And when both follow each other

```
[
  {
    followed: 'martha',
    follower: 'bob'
  }, {
    followed: 'bob',
    follower: 'martha'
  }
]
```

The only operation that is expensive with this design was also expensive in Design 1 and 2, for the same reason: we need to isolate common elements between two collections; that operation is finding the bidirectional relationships (e.g. bob and martha follow eachother).

As far as indexes go, only two have any use what so ever, `{ follower: 1, followed: 1 }` and `{ followed: 1, follower: 1 }` (and having both is only useful for sorting, as any one of those two would cover all filtering cases).

Now to come back to design 2, the use cas above would have been:

**bob follows martha**

`user_followers`

```
[
  {
    user: 'martha',
    follower: 'bob'
  }
]
```

`user_following`

```
[
  {
    user: 'bob',
    following: 'martha'
  }
]
```

**martha follows bob**

`user_followers`

```
[
  {
    user: 'bob',
    follower: 'martha'
  }
]
```

`user_following`

```
[
  {
    user: 'martha',
    following: 'bob'
  }
]
```

**bob and martha follow each other**

`user_followers`

```
[
  {
    user: 'bob',
    follower: 'martha'
  }, {
    user: 'martha',
    follower: 'bob'
  }
]
```

`user_following`

```
[
  {
    user: 'martha',
    following: 'bob'
  }, {
    user: 'bob',
    following: 'martha'
  }
]
```

Now we can see that, as I indicated, Design 2 would duplicate all follower information with absolutely no benefit what so ever.

Comment: This is not true. Each user can have any number of followers and may be following any number of others. Also I can follow bob and bob can follow me as well (eg. in twitter)

Comment: Yes, and then you will have in your single collection two entries: one with `{ followed: 'bob', follower: 'martha' }` and one with `{ followed: 'martha', follower: 'bob' }`. With two collections though, if bob follows martha you have to add an entry in the following collection **and** in the follower collection, basically registering that "bob is following martha" and that "bob is a follower of martha" (or "martha has bob as follower"), which is exactly the same thing!

Comment: @Gorkk: denormalization! :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev it does not do much though: there's no benefit in storing `(followed: a, follower: b)` in a collection and `(follower: b, followed: a)` in another, you just need to have an index on each of the two fields. With the first design, there is duplicated information overall, but with real benefit: in the user document you have its followers and its followees; when storing relations in an external collection, there's no benefit in duplicating that information.

Comment: How do you combine the followers and following array without sacrificing the query performance much?

Comment: with `(followed, follower)` and `(follower, followed)` keys (which you essentially have over two collections right now) you'll get the same performances (and even then having the two indexes would be useful mainly for sorting).

Comment: Gorkk, I am confused by your example of combining the 2 collections. bob <--> martha is not a common case but you may have cases where two people follows each other. Could you please use my example above and give me an example how to combine the 2 collections. I see one approach: {user: bob, other_user: martha, type: [1,2,3]} where 1 means bob -> martha, 2 means bob <- martha and 3 means bob <--> martha

Comment: If I have one collection with the type info then I can find all followers of bob by {user: bob, type: 1} and find all users bob is following: {user: bob, type: 2}

Comment: If I keep the type info then how do I find all people following martha? I need another index (other_user, type) in the single collection. How do you handle this?

Comment: For your use case, where "bob <--> martha", you would have two entries in the collection: `{ followed: bob, follower: martha }` and `{ followed: martha, follower: bob }`. Now to find all followers of bob, you just find entries matching `{ followed: bob }`. Now the only expansive operation (but this is also the case in your two original designs) would be to isolate the bidirectional relationships. As far as index goes, you'd have a `{ followed: 1, follower: 1}` index and a `{ follower: 1, followed: 1}` (though I'm not convinced both are needed besides for sorting).

Answer (score 1):

On a first look I see here that design 1 is very likely to create documents that are too big for mongo and the 16MB size limit can be an issue.

Also, have you thought of your indexes at all? I think it will be too bad for performance if you have to search for a relation inside a huge array of eg `users.following`. I think it is wiser to do it like the 2nd design. With that you can have simple indexes that will perform very good.

PS: Is there really a reason for both a `followers` and a `following` collection? maybe you can combine them in one.

Comment: Great! How do you combine the the following and followers? One approach - [{user: bob, other_user: mark, type: 1}, {user: bob, other_user: john, type: 2}, {user: bob, other_user: Von, type: 3}] Here type 1: bob -> mark, type 2: bob <- mark and type 3: bob <--> mark (means they follow each other) But this seems complicating the schema and queries. How do you combine the two?

Comment: maybe you can make `type` an array! `[{user: bob, other_user: mark, types: [1,2,3]}]`